# how to retrieve data from mongodb to javascript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently new to nodejs and mongodb, so please forgive me for this newbie type of question.

What I want is to pass data from my mongodb file to my js file which is running my mini-game.
What I am doing right now is using jsp tags to retrieve data from my mongodb (I am following this practice from a project that I have seen, but he is doing this on his html file which is working out well for him. for my case I was just trying my luck)

```
var win = <%= user.win %>;
var lose = <%= user.lose %>;
var draw = <%= user.draw %>;
```

How do I retrieve the data I had from my mongodb to javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an Node.JS with Express application, there are many ways to do it. If you're using a template engine, you could render the data as part of the HTML page in a `script` block (or render it directly as HTML, avoiding script). Or, you might want to use an Ajax style request and send back the data to the client.

```
app.get('/api/users/:id', function(req, res) {        
  Users.findOne({ _id : req.params.id }, function(error, user) {
    if (error || !user) {
      res.send({ error: error });
    } else {
      res.send(user);
    }
  });
});
```

Once you've got that ready, you could use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)'s `ajax` function for example to call the web service.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "api/users/" + userId,
}).done(function(user) {
    // here you have a  complete user object that you can use
});
```

The code you posted makes me think that you're using a template engine though. I would expect that there is a `render` method with your template HTML file:

```
res.render('homepage', user);
```

Then, in the HTML:

```
<script>
var win = <%= win %>;
var lose = <%= lose %>;
var draw = <%= draw %>;    
</script>
```

As the `user` object is the object with current context (as it was passed as the parameter in my example above), you can just directly refer to the properties of the `user` object directly (just `win` rather than `user.win`).